# How to reference two different Eclipse Dynamic web projects?

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-6

I have in eclipse project-A that's using some functions from project-B, in project-A's pom.xml i found this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>someId</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and it matches the `groupid` and `artifactId` in project-B's pom.xml and honestly i dont understand how it works.

### the problem

While debugging project-A i stepped over a function from project-B and it was shifted down by like 30 rows, the debugger was on line say 90, while the actual code beign executed ws on line 60.

### question

how does project referencing work ?

### note

there is also another folder in project-A called lib "WEB-INF/lib" and it has a jar packaging of project-B, but when debugging it doesnt go there at all.

### what i tried so far

- deleting the project-B.jar file found in my local Maven dependencies folder, cleaning, updating and rebuilding the project.
- deleting the folder found in "WEB-INF/lib" then cleaning, updating and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Please do a maven update on your project and try debugging again. If project a is version 2, and project b is including project a with version 2, then you can debug this two projects parallel. But if you updated project a to version 3 and now there is another code, those changes will not automatically be included in project b. You must define the version in the pom.xml of your main project and then do a maven update.

Comment: yes i did, didnt work, the debugger and actual code execution dont match.

Comment: View my comment, I just edited it.

Comment: i just checked project-b's pom.xml , and it matches what's referenced in project-A `<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`

Comment: And you did a maven update on project-a? If that's true, I do not have any idea of what could be the solution. Are you using tomcat? Maybe there is something cached.

Comment: yes i updated both projects , and i am using tomcat, i'm thinking about creating the manually instead of relying on maven to resolve the dependencies just to get it to work ,

Comment: If project-b has plenty of functions, but you only need 1 or 2, then this is in general a good idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245823/discussion-between-abdou-and-david-weber).

Comment: I would appreciate it, but I am currently working in my job. :D